# Unable to connect remote server error appears randomly after CSOM request

Tags: development, csom, internal-server-error

I'm currently working on a C# CSOM script for a SharePoint Online Instance that will return to me all the  items in a particular list that have no attachments. Everything seems to be working well but after this script runs successfully a number of times, the request returns "Unable to connect remote server error". Which persists until I restart my PC. The code I use is the one below:

```
        public static ListItemCollection GetListItemsWithoutAttachments(
       ClientContext ctx,
       string internalListName)
    {

        //get the SP List
        List oList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(internalListName);

        //initialize CAML query
        CamlQuery camlQuery;
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name=""Attachment"" /></IsNull></Where></Query></View>";

        //set query
        ListItemCollection resultLICollection = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

        ctx.Load(resultLICollection);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        return resultLICollection;
    }
```

The client context gets initialized this way:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Url);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, pass);
```